# How ios-WeChat 6.6.0 achieve this? New Notification style?Even Lock screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, wechat

When somebody video/voice call me on ios-wechat,the iOS notified me new style like phonecall. Even lock screen also*.*

is this new API? or notification style? or Apple for Tencent WeChat ONLY?

how can I achieve like WeChat?

[image: wechat 6.6.0 new notification]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CallKit, Same native interface for phone calls can be used- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit

This is an API introduced for iOS 10.0+